# Block login if too many login attempts

Tags: python, passwords

I want to "block login" or end code if user has too many attempts at entering a username or password but can try again by re-running the code

```
import time 
usernames = ("test","test01", "test02")
passwords = ("test", "test01", "test02")
while True:
    print("Username: ")
    username = input("")
    if username in usernames:
        print("Username Accepted")
    else:
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    break
while True:
    print("Password: ")
    password = input("")
    if password in passwords:
        print("Password Accepted")
    else:
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    break
print("Access Granted")
```

Comment: Cheat code: `^C` `↑` `Return` for an instant retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with "block login" or "end code" but here is one way to signal to calling code if the correct password was locked, or if it should be locked:

```
import time 

usernames = ("test", "test01", "test02")
passwords = ("test", "test01", "test02")


def username():
    print("Username: ")
    username = input("")
    if username in usernames:
        print("Username Accepted")
    else:
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    break

def password(n):
    while True:
        print("Password: ")
        password = input("")
        if password in passwords:
            print("Password Accepted")
            return True
         n -= 1
         if n == 0:
            return False
         print("Try Again (10 sec)")
         time.sleep(10)  

username()
if not password(3):
    print("Locked")
else:
    print("Access Granted")
```

It's best practice, btw, to not reveal if the username is correct.  In other words, you read (username, password) then you validate it and tell the user if the combination is correct.  Also, I would sleep 0 the first failure, but then make it [exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) worse each on each failure:

Answer (score 0):

Username and Password with validator

```
import time 
usernames = ("test","test01", "test02")
passwords = ("test", "test01", "test02")
max_attemp = 3

def validator(username, password):
    isValid = False
    if username in usernames and password in passwords:
        if (list(usernames).index(username) == list(passwords).index(password)):
            isValid = True
    return isValid



attemps = 0
while True:
    username = input("Your username:")
    password = input("Your password:")
    if validator(username, password):
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else:
        attemps+=1
        if attemps >= max_attemp:
            print("Exceed max attemps.")
            break
        
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSON file that stores the users credentials, as well as their attempts of login. The time_block key specifies the time and date based on your OS, which indicates how long that user will be blocked.

JSON file: users.json

```json
{
    "users" : 
    [
        {
            "username" : "test",
            "password" : "test",
            "blocked" : false,
            "attempts" : 0,
            "time_block" : ""
        },
        {
            "username" : "test01",
            "password" : "test01",
            "blocked" : false,
            "attempts" : 0,
            "time_block" : ""
        },
        {
            "username" : "test02",
            "password" : "test02",
            "blocked" : false,
            "attempts" : 0,
            "time_block" : ""
        }
        
    ]
}
```

Though I didn't include how long that user will be locked if he has too many attempts. You can try that if you want to.

```py
import time 
import json

max_attempts = 5

user_data = json.load(open('users.json'))

current_user = None

while True:
    print("Username: ")
    username = input("")

    is_user_found = [i[0] for i in enumerate(user_data["users"]) if i[1]["username"] == username]

    if (is_user_found):
        current_user = is_user_found
        if user_data["users"][current_user[0]]["blocked"]:
            print("User is locked")
            continue
        print("Username Accepted")

    else:
        print("Try Again (1 sec)")
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    break

while True:
    user_data["users"][current_user[0]]["attempts"] += 1
    
    print("Password: ")
    password = input("")
    
    if password == user_data["users"][current_user[0]]["password"]:
        user_data["users"][current_user[0]]["attempts"] = 0
        print("Password Accepted")
        print("Access granted")
        with open("users.json", "w") as output:
            json.dump(user_data, output)
        
    else:
        if user_data["users"][current_user[0]]["attempts"] >= max_attempts:
            user_data["users"][current_user[0]]["blocked"] = True

            with open("users.json", "w") as output:
                json.dump(user_data, output)
                
            print("Account locked")
            break
        print("Try Again (1 sec)")
        time.sleep(3)
        continue

    break
```